# Excel 2007 Graph scale showing blank dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have the below data:

```
Date       Planned Complete Carry Over   
11-May-18  1       0        1   
15-May-18  3       0        3  
16-May-18  6       0        6
```

When I insert a Bar Chart, it is showing "Blank" for 12-May-18, 13-May-2018 and 14-May-2018. But I do not have any activities and should not be displayed at all.
Please help.

Comment: Can you add an example of the chart so we understand the issue?  Also, are the dates on the X axis?  Is the X axis a timeline that should be chronologically proportioned, or are the dates just labels for successive data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using dates along your horizontal axis, Excel is trying to help by adding all the dates.  Since that's not what you want, you'll need to format your axis as text.  I don't have Excel 2007, but generally your process will be

1. Select your axis and right click
2. Choose format axis
3. Change axis type to Text (not date or automatic)

This should limit your axis items to just those you've explicitly listed, and not all possible dates within the range of your values.